# Angular JS: TypeError: PagePath is not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am getting following errors while executing Jasmine Angular JS Unit Test Case:-

> Error: ReferenceError: PagePath is not defined

My code is as follows:-

```
describe('Patient Defect Management', function () {

beforeEach(module('myApp'));
var $controller;
var $httpBackend;
var myService;

beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
$controller = _$controller_;
}));

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

$httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
myService = $injector.get("angularService");
}));

afterEach(function() {
$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();

});

it('NextAccountDetails', function () {

var $scope = {};
var controller = $controller('PatientDefectManagementCtrl', { $scope: $scope      });
var returnData = {"FacilityCode": "ABCD", "ID": "1540447"};
$httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:8081/Accretive.Tasks.PatientDefectManagement/Services/PatientManagement.asmx/GetDetails").respond(returnData);

var returnedPromise = myService.get('1234', 'test');
var result;
returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
    result = response.data;
});

expect(result).toEqual(returnData);
$httpBackend.flush();
 });
```

links in my index.html

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/jasmine.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.3/boot.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular and Angular Mock references -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>



<script src="/Angular/Module.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/Service.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/Controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/AngularJSUnitTest/UnitTest.js"></script>
```

PagePath is not defined is the error I am getting now. This is what I need to resolve now.
Please help

Comment: PagePath is defined in service.js page, which I need to mock, can anyone please tell how can I mock it. `var Url = PagePath`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you placed afterEach() hook inside it() test case. This is incorrect. Move it next to the beforeEach().

First error usually means that you did something wrong in test runner (karma?) configuration and js file containing you service was not loaded, or you misspelled service name. Something like that. It's hard to say what exactly is wrong since you did not show this part of code.

Comment: Test runner is Jasmine

Comment: @rahul, still not enoug information. Need to see at least how components are registered with angular in your application and test runner configuration (jasmine is an assertion library, not a test runner).